# Dynamic Struct Array Being Allocated to infinite size

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory, realloc

my task is to write a struct which reads data from file and realloc more memory if needed.
So Far I have done this:
**The Struct:**

```
typedef struct myprog
{
    int id;
    char name[100];
    int price;
}myprog;
```

**Read Function:**

```
myprog* readFromFile(FILE* fP, char fileName[], myprog* reg, int* size)
{
    fP = fopen(fileName, "r");      //Open Input File as read

    if (fP == NULL)   //If File is not found, do nothing
    {
        printf("File does not exist.");
    }
    else    //Else read file line by line
    {
        printf("\nReading from File");
        int x = 0;
        char line[100];
        char* split;
        char* args[4];
        while (fgets(line, 100, fP))  //Read the first line
        {
            if (x == MAX)    //If Max Size is reached, increase it twice
            {
                int new_size = MAX * 2;
                reg = (struct vara*)realloc(reg, new_size * sizeof(struct vara));   //Even if i comment these lines the code works :O
            }

            split = strtok(line, " ");      //Split the line on space delimiter i.e {"1", "apple", "10"}
            args[0] = split;

            int i = 1;
            while (split != NULL)
            {
                split = strtok(NULL, " ");
                args[i] = split;
                i++;
            }

            if (i != 3) //Checking if the args size is three
            {
                //Copy from args to struct
                reg[x].id = atoi(args[0]);  //Copy Number
                strcpy(reg[x].name, args[1]);   //Copy Name
                reg[x].price = atoi(args[2]);  //Copy Balance
                x++;
            }
        }
        (*size) = x;
        printf("\nReading Completed!");
        fclose(fP);
    }
    return reg;
}
```

**Main Function:**

```
void main()
{
    char fileName[100];
    FILE* fP = NULL;
    printf("Enter file Name : ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    myprog* reg = malloc(MAX * sizeof * reg); //#define MAX 1
    int size = 0;
    reg = readFromFile(fP, fileName, reg, &size);
    //Some Code below
}
```

**The Problem I am facing:**
When I run the code with MAX defined with 1, it reads any number of products from file without any memory leak errors. It even works without the realloc, can you please help me identify my mistake?
The data in input file is like this:

```
1 prod_a 15
2 prod_b 20
```

Comment: You need to increase `MAX` after you reallocate, so you'll know when you get to the new max.

Comment: Or define `int new_size` earlier, and then `if(x >= new_size) { new_size += MAX; /*etc*/}`.

Comment: You're using `sizeof * reg`, which is equivalent to `sizeof(*reg)`, but you should be using `sizeof(reg)`.